# Why am I hitting the sane container with different prefix folders

Tags: istio

Do you know why the following two istio yaml prefix configurations, is routed to the same container?

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-one-virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways: 
  - my-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /one
    route:
    - destination:
        host: my-one-service
```

The following is hitting the same container/service(just changed the prefix and host service):

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-two-virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways: 
  - my-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /one/two
    route:
    - destination:
        host: my-two-service
```

Comment: Could you provide whole config, because it is not clear where the miss configuration?

Comment: Thanks, just updated the question - hope it makes more sense

Comment: Does it get routed to `my-one-service` all the time?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you have 2 virtual services for the same host. In this case the rules will be merged in undefined order as described [here](https://istio.io/help/ops/traffic-management/deploy-guidelines/#multiple-virtual-services-and-destination-rules-for-the-same-host).

In your case, since the second prefix is a more specific subset of the first, you need to make sure that the second rule has higher priority (i.e., is ordered first).

You can fix it by putting both rules into a single virtual service, like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-one-virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways: 
  - my-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /one/two
    route:
    - destination:
        host: my-two-service
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /one
    route:
    - destination:
        host: my-one-service
```

More information about rule ordering can be found [here](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#precedence).